# getting an 'int' object is not iterable error for a numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So this is part of my code which is causing an error.
assignments is a dictionary with the key and the indices of the numpy array as items.
data and centroids are arrays.

I am unable to figure out why i get the error 
'int' object is not iterable when the 'try' line is being executed. Sometimes it works just fine but sometimes it doesn't.
Any help will be highly appreciated

```
for key in self.assignments:
    clust_sum = 0
    for k in self.assignments[key]:
        clust_sum += data[k]
    print(key, clust_sum)
    try:
        self.centroids[key] = [
        m / len(self.assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: `clust_sum` is an integer, and you wrote `... for m in clust_sum`.  The error message tells you what happens when you try that: you can't iterate over an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `for m in clust_sum`, `clust_sum` is an `int` and you can't iterate over an `int` object. I don't know exactly what you want to do, but if you want to run your `for loop` the number of `clust_sum` times you can do like this:

```
for key in self.assignments:
clust_sum = 0
for k in self.assignments[key]:
    clust_sum += data[k]
print(key, clust_sum)
try:
    self.centroids[key] = [
    m / len(self.assignments[key]) for m in range(clust_sum)]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `for m in clust_sum` wiith `for m in range(0,clust_sum)`.